# getting error in pod installation in ios

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, podfile

i want to implement `Google Drive` in my `iOS` Project , but i am not able to install `pod` for `GTMAppAuth` please can you suggest how we can install pod with `GTMAppAuth` valid path and version

[!] Unable to find a specification for `GTMAppAuthhttps://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did u used pod update after pod init , pod install ?

Comment: Show your podfile. Check documentation here for google drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart. Make sure to follow the tutorial.

Comment: pod 'GoogleAPIClient/Drive', '~> 1.0.2'
pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.0'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'

Comment: how to add this in above  podfile GTMAppAuth

Comment: https://guides.cocoapods.org/. Use this to understand how to create pod.

Comment: Thanks @New16 for reply , but i want to add  GTMAppAuth in podfile but my problem is this i am not able to set exact source of this file in podfile with  latest version of  GTMAppAuth . can you please help me out

Comment: `pod 'GTMAppAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth.git'`, use this in the pod.

Comment: hi @New16 i have tried with this but i am getting this error :-
  [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AppAuth (~> 0.7.0)` required by `GTMAppAuth (0.5.0)`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `AppAuth (~> 0.7.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

Comment: I am able to pod install the pod 'GTMAppAuth'. This depends on few other pods as well.

Comment: can you please update me what some more pods file you have included . please Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129901/discussion-between-jaydev-and-new16).